# Global Name 'line' not defined

Tags: python, python-2.7, scope

I am writing a function to read data from files in the given directory but running into scoping issues

```
def get_json_file(content_type, proc_date):
    filenames = glob.glob('/home/*')
    with open('/home/tgfile', 'w') as outfile:
            for fname in filenames:
                    print ('line 1..')
                    with open(fname) as infile:
                            print ('line 2..')
                            with line in infile:
                                    print ('line 3..')
                                    outfile.write(line)
get_json_file('dir', '20180122')
```

Here is the error message:

> File "gen_json_file.py", line 17, in 
>       get_json_file('SENTIMENT_ANNOTATION', '20180122')
>     File "gen_json_file.py", line 12, in get_json_file
>       with line in infile:
>   NameError: global name 'line' is not defined

I The program outputs line 1, line 2 debug statements but fails at outfile.write(line). I made a declaration of 'line' variable as global but that does not help.

Comment: Replace `with line in infile:` with `for line in infile:`

Comment: Great..it worked!! Would you comment, I can mark it as correct answer

Answer (score 1):

@Mark Dickinson's comment is correct, you're using `with` where you want `for`.

You probably also want to open the input files as read explicitly for clarity

```
def get_json_file(content_type, proc_date):
    filenames = glob.glob('/home/*')
    with open('/home/tgfile', 'w') as outfile:
            for fname in filenames:
                    print ('line 1..')
                    with open(fname, 'r') as infile:
                            print ('line 2..')
                            for line in infile:
                                    print ('line 3..')
                                    outfile.write(line)
get_json_file('dir', '20180122')
```

Comment: That's right..it worked!